# Smart-cast and comparison inside When Expression after 'is' type-check

Tags: java, kotlin

According to the documentation for [When Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression), it can replace "if-else if", so I tried implementing a function to return maximum of two variable of `Any` type:

```
fun maxOf(a: Any, b: Any) = when {
    a is Int && b is Int        -> if (a < b) b else a
    a is Double && b is Double  -> if (a < b) b else a
    a is Int && b is Double     -> if (a < b) b else a
    a is Double && b is Int     -> if (a < b) b else a
    a is String && b is String  -> if (a < b) b else a
    else                        -> null
}
```

The above implementation works but I thought it could be more concise:

```
fun maxOf(a: Any, b: Any) = when {
    (a is Int || a is Double) && (b is Int || b is Double) -> if (a < b) b else a
    a is String && b is String                             -> if (a < b) b else a
    else                                                   -> null
}
```

But I failed because the second implementation doesn't work; the error is in the first occurrence of `if (a < b)`:

> Unresolved references.
>
> None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch
>
> • **public fun String.compareTo(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean =...): Int** *defined in* kotlin.text

Is this because smart-cast is not capable of casting `a` and `b` to their actual types after evaluating the expression `(a is Int || a is Double) && (b is Int || b is Double)`? Or am I missing something?

### Update

The same error happens even if the type of `a` and `b` is changed to `Number`:

```
fun maxOf(a: Number, b: Number) = when {
    (a is Int || a is Double) && (b is Int || b is Double) -> if (a < b) b else a
    else                                                   -> null
}
```

Comment: why are you not using Comparable?

Comment: @njzk2 Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: nvm, that wouldn't work for comparing ints to doubles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why this happen?

It's not a problem of `when` expression. You should blame on the type system.

`a` and `b` are instance of `Int` and `Double`, so Kotlin will infer them as their LCA. For example:

```
open class A { fun a() = println("meow meow meow") }
class B : A()
class C : A()
if (a is B || a is C) a.a() // smart cast works
```

However, `Int` and `Double` are subclasses of `Number` and `Comparable` at the same time, and Kotlin doesn't know if you want a `Number` or a `Comparable`, so Kotlin treat it as an instance of `Any`.

```
if (a is Int || a is Double)
  if (a > 1) print("meow meow") // smart cast doesn't work
```

This is why the "bug" appears.

### How to fix this?

<del>Use your original code, or use explicit cast (I know it sucks, but it **is** really an unavoidable problem).</del>

I've came up with a beautiful solution! Look at it:

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> maxOf(a: T, b: T): T? = when {
    (a is Int || a is Double) && (b is Int || b is Double) -> if (a < b) b else a
    a is String && b is String -> if (a < b) b else a
    else -> null
}
```

And in this way, you can apply any `Comparable` to it (instead of `Int`, `Double` and `String` only)!

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> maxOf(a: T, b: T): T = if (a < b) b else a
```

Your original version will return `null` if input is invalid, and this version will raise compilation error if input is invalid, helping you find error at compile time.

#### Mention!

You've commented me and asked a further question. I want to make my reply more readable so I'll add it to my answer.

```
fun someFunction(a: Number) {
    if (a is Int || a is Double) println(a < 1) // still error! Why?!
}
```

Yeah, indeed, `a` is an instance of `Number` here.
But please do mention, `<`, or, `compareTo`, is **not** declared in `Number`. It's in `Int` or `Double` :).

### Edit 2

You said:

> using generics forces `a` and `b` to be the same type.

So try this:

```
fun <A : Comparable<B>, B : Any> maxOf(a: A, b: B): Any = if (a < b) b else a
```

And you said:

> explicit cast is not a solution if the type of `a` and `b` is `Any`

- solution zero: create `operator fun Any.compareTo`
- solution one: Give up casting.

Comment: "`Int` and `Double` are subclasses of `Number` and `Comparable`... Kotlin treat it as an instance of `Any`.", mentioned in your answer.

But if I enforce `a` to be a `Number`, the following still doesn't work: `fun printMeow(a :Number) { if (a is Int || a is Double) if (a > 1) print("meow") }`

So I'm not quite sure if that's true.

Comment: Edited and answered your question.

Comment: Hey! I've just came up with an extremely beautiful solution, please take a look! I feel super smart now :D

Comment: Well at least smart-cast is smart enough to know type `T` is the same as `T` and perform the comparison.

Comment: It's not smart cast's job. It's generics'.

Comment: interesting that all children of Number implement Comparable, but Number does not...

Comment: I think you're solution is useful to know but is not the solution to my problem. REASON: 1) using generics forces `a` and `b` to be the same type. 2) explicit cast is not a solution if the type of `a` and `b` is `Any` (i.e. I couldn't explicitly cast `a` or `b` to `Double` for instance to be able to perform the comparison)